# activating jquery tabber based on link URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to jquery and I decided to build a jquery tabber. So far so good but I have a little problem!!! I cant see how I can activate the tabber based on the URL. For instance when the link is www.myweb.com#tab2, the second tabber becomes activated. My jquery is as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // When page loads...
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    // On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });

});
```

and HTML list as follows

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Design Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Publications</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Awards &amp; Recognitions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">Our Mission</a></li>
    <li class="last-item"><a href="#tab1">Company Profile</a></li>
</ul>
```

now when someone visit my website with this link `www.mywebsite.com#tab3`, I want tab3 to be activated. I know jquery tabber has this but I don't know how achieve this with my own jquery tabber. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: you want have tab3 in href link !! if you provide tab2 in url it will work.. and by the it's not to relate with jquery,tabber its simple html hyperlink rule to navigate inside page...

Comment: yep typo fixed that. Can you answer my question now?

Comment: this dude said he didn't want jquery's tabber so why suggest it?

Comment: `Trigger` `click` event based on ur hash location. Follow this answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704186/activating-jquery-tabber-based-on-link-url#15706208

Answer (score 0):

Activate an item with `href` attribute equal to `location.hash`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var hash = location.hash;
   $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
   if ($("ul.tabs li a[href='" + hash + "']").length) { //check if such link exists
      $("ul.tabs li a[href='" + hash + "']").parent().addClass("active"); //Activate tab
      $(hash).show();
   }
   else {
      $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass('active');
      $(".tab_content:first").show()
   }       
}
```

Comment: it's a typo sorry! I'll fix that right away. in the mean time let me check what you did and hope it works

Comment: ok almost the solution but this is the logic I'm trying to achieve. If there is a # location activate that particular tab else, activate the first tab. Since there's no if else statement in jquery I don't know how to achieve this

Comment: It works perfectly for one selector. However, I have 3 selectors `ul#tabs li`, `ul#tabs li a`, `ul.tabs li a` and that is when the code fails to work. below is the if code:

 `if ($("ul#tabs li[href='" + hash + "']").length, $("ul#tabs li a[href='" + hash + "']").length, $("ul.tabs li a[href='" + hash + "']").length) 
   
            { //check if such link exists
       $("ul#tabs li [href='" + hash + "'], ul#tabs li a[href='" + hash + "'], ul.tabs li a[href='" + hash + "']").parent().addClass("active"); //Activate tab
       $(hash).show();
   }`

Comment: Consider editing your question then. Next time, specify, what exactly you want to do.

Comment: ouch so your not gonna help me out? :(

Comment: I can't quite understand, what are you planning to do. You'd better make a working example on http://jsfiddle.net/ and describe, what behaviour do you expect.

Comment: what I want to achieve is for the //check if hash exist, you did this:- `if ($("ul.tabs li a[href='" + hash + "']").length) {//do stuff}`

now I want to check if hash exist for both `ul.tabs li a` and `ul#tabs li a` so I selected both but it's not working

and I don't know how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple. You can `trigger` `click` event based on your hash index.

This will work for you. If you refresh the page after clicking for say tab3 and your url contains hash index `#tab3`, your third tab will be focused automatically.

I assume that you have an id `tab1`, `tab2`, `tab3`, `tab4` in your `li` or `a` tag and its viola. 

 Add these codes to your existing code without affecting them and you are done.

```
$(function(){
    if(location.href.indexOf('#') != -1){
        var namedAnchor = window.location.hash;
        var findToTab = namedAnchor;
        $(findToTab).trigger('click');
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

How ever if you don't want to assign any ids to either `li` or `a` tag, you can do this.

```
$(function(){
    if(location.href.indexOf('#') != -1){
        var namedAnchor = window.location.hash;
        var findToTab = namedAnchor;
        $("ul.tabs li a[href='" + findToTab + "']").trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Comment: I have 3 selectors `ul#tabs li`, `ul#tabs li a`, `ul.tabs li a` how do I make this work?

Comment: If you can provide me your full html for the tab page, so I can analyze and and make it to work for you and will post back u the solution.